# Complex PG regex query

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have the following working function which is used in check constraint (I'll only post the relevant SQL part):

```
  -- a comma should always be followed by a space
  -- a period should always be followed by a space, except if it is the last character of the string OR the string contains 'caporal'
  -- a question mark should always be followed by a space, except if it is the last character of the string
  -- must not contain 2 or more spaces in a row
  -- must not contain ((
  -- must not contain ))
  -- any open parenthesis should be closed: number of '(' should equal to number of ')'
  SELECT
    ($1 !~ ',(?!\s)|\s{2}|[?](?!\s(?!$)|$)|[()]{2,}') AND
    ((array_length(string_to_array($1, '('), 1) - 1) = (array_length(string_to_array($1, ')'), 1) - 1)) AND
    ($1 ~ 'caporal' OR $1 !~ '[.](?!\s(?!$)|$)')
```

Overtime I realized that I need to allow a period without a following space for the cases:

- `.fr`
- `.com`
- `.net`
- `.co.uk`

Also, I realized that I need to allow float numbers to be written with comma/period as separator. The following cases should be valid:

- `2,5cm`
- `10.4l`

I was trying multiple things but it seems I'm just breaking the existing rules instead of adding "exceptions" to them.

My latter attempt was the following:

```
  SELECT
    ($1 !~ '[[a-zA-Z]àâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ],(?!\s)|\s{2}|[?](?!\s(?!$)|$)|[()]{2,}') AND
    ((array_length(string_to_array($1, '('), 1) - 1) = (array_length(string_to_array($1, ')'), 1) - 1)) AND
    ($1 ~ 'caporal' OR $1 !~ '[[a-zA-Z]àâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ][.](?!\s(?!$)|(?!fr)|(?!com)|$)')
```

But it clearly isn't what I want. Thank you in advance for hints and advices!

Comment: Try changing the first regex to `,(?!\d(?<=\d,\d)|\s)|\s{2}|\?(?!\s(?!$)|$)|[()]{2,}` and the last one to `\.(?!\d(?<=\d\.\d)|(?:fr|com|co\.uk|(?<=\yco\.)uk|net)\y|\s(?!$)|$)`. It should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the first regex to

```sql
,(?!\d(?<=\d,\d)|\s)|\s{2}|\?(?!\s(?!$)|$)|[()]{2,}
```

and the last one to

```sql
\.(?!\d(?<=\d\.\d)|(?:fr|com|co\.uk|(?<=\yco\.)uk|net)\y|\s(?!$)|$)
```

The changes are additions to the negative lookaheads that fail the match if their patterns match immediately to the right of the current location.

In the first case, `,(?!\d(?<=\d,\d)|\s)` is  used to match any comma that is not followed with a whitespace or any digit that is a fractional digit (as it must be preceded with a digit and a comma).

In the second regex, a similar restriction is added, see `\d(?<=\d\.\d)` that makes the `\.` match a dot that is not the first fractional digit in a float number with a period as a decimal separator, and the `(?:fr|com|co\.uk|(?<=\yco\.)uk|net)\y` part is added to avoid matching a `.` that is followed with `fr`, `com`, `co.uk`, the second period in `co.uk` (`(?<=\yco\.)uk` lookbehind makes sure that the comma before `uk` not preceded with `co.` is still matched) or `net` as whole words (see `\y`, word boundary).